# Final 2 errors of code need to be solved. _CGRectIntersectsRect

Tags: ios, cgrect

I had a test app from 2 years ago which code i'm now trying to move into my current app and i've cleared up most of the problems with it aside from 2 which have stumped me (3 am). Probably something I have simply overlooked but i'm a bit rusty with XCode as I haven't used it since the test app. Been developing with Eclipse the past few years

> Error 1: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_CGRectIntersectsRect", referenced from:
>         -[GameViewController gameStatePlayNormal] in GameViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Error 2:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:   "_CGRectIntersectsRect",
>   referenced from:
>         -[GameViewController gameStatePlayNormal] in GameViewController.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Or more directly:

```
#import <CoreGraphics/CoreGraphics.h>
```

Comment: thanks fixed issue. I feel like an idiot now! Forgot to add a framework... Silly me and Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you have to do more than just add one of those two import lines (same error occurs with them). What was it that user1319017 meant about adding a framework?

Comment: Maybe he actually had to _link_ against the framework, but the error would be identical all the same, and my suggestion fixed his problem.